# bitrix, php: <p class="contacts-coords__location"><?= __('contacts.locations.name_1') ?></p>

Tags: php

Как php интерпретирует строку, указанную в скобках?
Мне известно, что php функция __('какой-нибудь текст') используется для локализации указанного текста.
Но в моём случае текст один ('contacts.locations.name_1'), а отображение его на сайте другое (обычный "человеческий" текст - индекс, город, улица и т.д.). Что нужно сделать чтобы изменить отображаемый текст на сайте?

Comment: Сомневаюсь что в битриксе есть функция `__`. Может это все-таки вордпресс?

Comment: Нет, это точно битрикс, и строка из одного из php файлов.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Дело было в том, что строка, указанная в скобках __('contacts.locations.name_1') интерпретировалась не просто как строка, а как, если я не ошибаюсь, ключ c полным путём. Осознав это, и немного разобравшись со структурой bitrix сайта, я нашёл файл php с название contacts, в котором был массив ключ/значение, в котором был мой ключ locations.name_1. Поправив соответствующее ему значение, изменился текст на сайте.